# How to "Save" a particular picture inside a div that was replaced using a function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got the codes from another answered question from this site. But what I want is that i want to make a button that saves the newly uploaded picture inside the div. As in if i refresh the page, the newly uploaded pic is there and not the old one.

HTML:

```
   <div id="profilepic">
        <img src = "Anonymous.png" class = "profilepic" height="200px" width="200px"><br/>
    </div>
    <form id="changepic">
    <br/><input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" onchange="readURL(this)"><br/>
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
    $(".imageSection button").click(function() {
        $(".imageSection img").removeClass("activeImage");
        $(this).parent().find("img").addClass("activeImage");
    });
    $(".imageSection:eq(0) img").addClass("activeImage");

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('.profilepic,.activeImage').attr('src', e.target.result).width(200).height(200);

                $('.activeImage').css('display', 'inline');
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

In this code, when i upload a picture image.jpg, it will replace the picture anonymous.png with image.jpg. Now what i want is, when the picture is changed, it will be permanent (like when i refresh the page, go to another page then go back again) unless i want to change it again. (it must be like a change profile picture feature in facebook,twitter, etc.)

Comment: you'll have to save it to the db or a file maybe...

Comment: what you call php, looks pretty much like javascript :)

Comment: you can check with php if image.jpg exists then use it instead of anonymous.png initially `<img src = "<?=(file_exists("image.jpg"))?"image.jpg":"Anonymous.png"?>" ...`  Or use php sessions to detect if user uploaded image previously

Comment: You're going to need to use PHP to save the file to a specific location. Have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for an upload tutorial with PHP. If you name the new image the same as the old one, it will overwrite it and you won't have to change the `src` attribute in your `<img>` tags.